# Thread name and calling run method twice

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point, runnable

I'm studying i saw following in my sample test.
I'm not quite sure why below code print "First".

When i debug it seems as MyRunnable.run is called twice.
Does this mean run method is always called twice even in other scenario?

```
public class currentThreadName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("First");
        MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable("MyRunnable");
        mr.run();       
    }

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    MyRunnable(String name) {
        new Thread(this, name).start();
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `run` method is called twice.

One call is by calling `start()` in the `MyRunnable` constructor; this is executed in the separate thread.  That prints "MyRunnable".

However, you also call `run` directly in `main`, which is executed in the main thread.  This is responsible for the output "First", since you assigned the name "First" to the main thread.

Normally, you shouldn't call `run` directly; call `start` only.  This will call `run` in the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mr.run();` and `new Thread(this, name).start();` so yes it is running twice.

I suggest you only use `start` to execute your new thread. Why?

Because if you just call `run()` directly, it will be executed on the calling thread (like any other method call).

However, if you call `Thread.start()` it will **actually create a new thread** so that the runnable's run method is executed in parallel.

Comment: Thnx but why is "Frist" always prints first or before "MyRunnable" is printed? is it true that when <pre>.start()</pre> is called we dont know when it will get excuted? since JVM doesn't guarranty anything

Comment: "First" prints first because it executes before the rest of the code. Your second statement is correct, if two threads are alive at the same time it is not guaranteed which will run first.

Comment: Is it okay to instantiate your runnable object and then call its start method more than once?  Will it create a new thread each time?